# Providing a .env file in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How do I provide a .env file in Kubernetes. I am using a Node.JS package that populates my process.env via my .env file.

Comment: You don't. You create Secrets or ConfigMaps and expose those values as environment variables. See e.g. [these docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Providing env variable for the container:
   During creation of a pod, you can set environment variables for the containers that run in that Pod. To set environment variables, include the `env` field in the configuration file.

ex:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

2. Using ConfigMaps:
   first you need to create a ConfigMaps, ex is below, here `data` field refers your values in a key-value pair.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: special-config
  namespace: default
data:
  SPECIAL_LEVEL: very
  SPECIAL_TYPE: charm
```

Now, use `envFrom` to define all of the ConfigMap's data as container environment variables, ex:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```

you can even specify individual field by giving `env` like below:

```
      env:
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: special-config
              key: SPECIAL_LEVEL
        - name: SPECIAL_TYPE_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: special-config
              key: SPECIAL_TYPE
```

Ref: [configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data) and [env set](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for me it is confusing to have alle the Varaibles in the main Pod file. So your config map is in a seperate file called special-config.yaml or how is it done? Background is that I want to copy different files there depending on the system.

Comment: @Matt yes the config map will be in separate yaml file, basically it’s a separate k8s object, and you can have any number of configmap and refer those in pods yaml as env